# Obter value checkbox criado via javascript DOM

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom

Tenho uma função javascript que cria elementos checkbox dinamicamente no html para criação de um formulário de perguntas. Preciso obter todos esses **checkbox independente se forem marcados ou não pois estou passando o titulo no value** para salvar no banco de dados e posteriormente serem recriados em uma página.

Html

```
<form class="form" action="">
    <input class="form-input" type="text" data-form-input>
    <button class="form-button" data-form-button>Adicionar</button>
</form> 
<form action="save.php" method="POST">
    <ul class="list" data-list>
    </ul>
    
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Salvar">
</form>
<script src="src/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
const criarTarefa = (evento) => {
    evento.preventDefault()
    const input = document.querySelector('[data-form-input]')
    const valor = input.value

    const list = document.querySelector('[data-list]')
    const tarefa = document.createElement('li')
    const conteudo = `<input type="checkbox" data-checkbox name="resposta[]" value="${valor}"> ${valor}</input>`

    tarefa.innerHTML = conteudo
    list.appendChild(tarefa)

    input.value = ""
}

const novaTarefa = document.querySelector('[data-form-button]')

const input = document.querySelector('[data-form-input]')

novaTarefa.addEventListener('click', criarTarefa)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não estou conseguindo enviar via **$_POST** e **php**. Como poderia obter via javascript e passar para o php?

Answer (score 0):

Tente `querySelectorAll`:

```
var chks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
```

```js
function add() {
  let div = document.getElementById('check');
  div.innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" />';
}

function showChecks () {
  var chks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

  var tamanho = chks.length;

  for(i=0; i < tamanho; i++){
    console.log(chks[i])
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="add()">add check</button>
<div id="check">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<button onClick="showChecks()">mostrar checkboxs</button>
```